# Counting the net change in patches with a certain color in Netlogo

Tags: java, plot, netlogo, patch

I want to measure the rate of change of patches from green to red.
Using the community fire model in Netlogo, how do I determine the number of tree patches that just turned red aka new burned trees?

Comment: What options have you already tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.